# android- can you make an object drawn in a canvas clickable

Tags: android, loops, view, onclick, android-canvas

I know that the canvas in android is a lower level drawing surface but currently Im drawing all my objects inside a canvas and I would like a better way to handle clicks for each object on the canvas. Ive tried matching an x and y through the view their drawn in and that only works some of the time.

Is there anyway to make the individual bitmaps Im drawing im my canvas clickable. The objects in my app are moving dynamically...think of a game object where on screen elements are moving. Ive tried creating a class that extended Button but everything got drawn in the upper right hand corner of the screen so Im not sure if you can have moving objects onscreen that extend button however at least when I clicked the image on top of the stack of ones drawn it gave the expected response. Right now I register onscreen clicks through the view that the canvas is drawn in and through the running loop that makes on screen action take place I have an array of all items and when a click is registered I loop through all the items and those that are onscreen are checked for their coordinates. if I get a match i fire an intent to perform an action.....like I said this is unreliable at best and Im momentarily at a loss on how to restructure everything to get reliable responses.

Comment: Hi, I am working on an app that involves moving objects drawn on canvas. Can you tell me how you were able to move an object once drawn on a canvas.

Comment: I was using the sensors of the device to get constant updates which I in turn used to figure out which direction and heading the phone was pointing in. I then used a boat load of math to constantly update the position of objects based on the realworld position of the phone. I ended up using an open source opengl es engine called min3d. The original author has since moved on to another engine he developed so there isnt much support for it but I was able to rip it apart and get it to do what I wanted. If your going to use just a canvas you should look at how some 2d game engines work.

Comment: more than likely youll need to create some kind of state machine or extend a view and do the updating of the onscreen objects in the views ondraw call. Thats how I did it. Take a look at some open source augmented reality engines that run on android. They usually extend a view and do all the drawing which updates the onscreen objects just how I explained up above.